# Setting margins with esami package

Tags: margins, esami

Is there a way to customize the margins of the document while using the `esami` package? I've tried `geometry`, `fullpage`, etc., with no success. The documentation says nothing about doing such thing.

Comment: Can you make a small example to play with?

Comment: I used `testA.tex`, which is an example file provided by the package. Since `esami` needs a `cfg` file to work, I decided it was best to leave out a MWE (since it couldn't be a *working* example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The margins are defined in the language configuration file (for instance, `es-UKenglish.lng`): at line 56 of that file, you can find the `geometry` package with some options defined.
If you want to customize these options, in the master file you can use, before `\begin{document}` and after having loaded the `esami` package, the command `\geometry{your custom option}`.